# Python - Plotly: How to set the text annotation at the centre of a rectangle?

Tags: python, plotly

I have created shaded areas in a `plotly.express` box plot and I need to populate the text annotation at the top center of it.

The piece of code is as follows:

```
    fig = px.box(data_frame = df,
                 x = 'N_ppm', y = 'N_dose',
                 color = 'pH_characterisation',
                 points = False,
                 facet_row = 'soil_text_3',
                 facet_col = 'org_mat_characterisations',
                 category_orders = {
                     'soil_text_3' : ['E', 'M', 'B']
                     }
                 )

    fig.add_vrect(x0 = point_E,
                  x1 = top,
                  annotation_text="E",
                  annotation_position="top left",
                  fillcolor="green",
                  opacity=0.2,
                  line_width=0)
```

And it produces a plot like the following:

[image]

As it is shown, the letter 'E' is at the top left corner whereas I need it to be at the top center space of the green rectangle. I have not been able to figure out what are the allowed options I have, but 'top center' is not one of them, while 'top' is the same as 'top left'.

Do you have any ideas how to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- have synthesised data frame to be able to run your code,  plus defined `point_E` and `top`
- if you inspect the layout that has been created,  you will see `add_vrect()` has created **annotations** that contain the text *E*
- these can be modified by doing a list comprehension to update the **x** position of this annotation

#### full code

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import plotly.express as px

n = 3000
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "N_ppm": np.random.randint(1, 10, n),
        "N_dose": np.random.randint(1, 50, n),
        "pH_characterisation": np.random.choice(list("ABC"), n),
        "soil_text_3": np.random.choice(list("EMB"), n),
        "org_mat_characterisations": np.random.choice(list("XYZ"), n),
    }
)

point_E = 3
top = 7

fig = px.box(
    data_frame=df,
    x="N_ppm",
    y="N_dose",
    color="pH_characterisation",
    points=False,
    facet_row="soil_text_3",
    facet_col="org_mat_characterisations",
    category_orders={"soil_text_3": ["E", "M", "B"]},
)

fig.add_vrect(
    x0=point_E,
    x1=top,
    annotation_text="E",
    annotation_position="top left",
    fillcolor="green",
    opacity=0.2,
    line_width=0,
)

fig.update_layout(
    annotations=[
        a if a["text"] != "E" else {**a, **{"x": ((top - point_E) / 2) + point_E}}
        for a in fig.to_dict()["layout"]["annotations"]
    ]
)
```

#### output

*E* has been entered.

[image]

Comment: Could you explain some more about the ```else``` part? What if I add a new vertical rectangle with another annotation?

Comment: there are multiple annotations some created by **px** for facet names.  the `else` should just modify **x** of the ones that have been created by `add_vrect()` and the text is the text assigned in that operation